# Spring generic (parameterized type) conversion service?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create a generic Converter for Spring that will allow incoming Enum values to be mixed case and converted toUpper prior to mapping to the enum.

The conversion works well for any specific Enum type we're using when the Converter is defined for a specific enum type. However when I write this as a generic Spring never calls the code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

// Doesn't work, Spring doesn't appear to allow Converters with type parameters :-(
@Component
public class StringToEnumConverter <T extends Enum> implements Converter<String, T> {

    @Override
    public T convert(String string) {
        Type type = ((ParameterizedType)StringToEnumConverter.class.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return (T) Enum.valueOf((Class<T>)type, string.trim().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Is the code incorrect or is it that Spring doesn't know how to match the type at runtime? I was hoping that `T extends Enum` is enough information for Spring to send all Enum subclasses through here.

Answer (score -2):

Enum type is final in java architecture desgin you shouldn't create a class that extends this type in your project.

Reference:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/java-extend-enum)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511453/extending-a-enum-in-java)

Comment: <T extends Enum> is not "extending" Enum, it says this generic type can be of type Enum or a subclass... it's strictly for type matching bounds.