# Extendable enum in Java without using extends

Tags: java, enums, extends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to extend Java Enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642281/is-it-possible-to-extend-java-enums)

I have a little issue where I have a enum with a certain number of values. This enum is used in multiple parts of the system and in some cases needs to contain some more values.

Since extending enums isnt allowed in Java I've tried to think of some alternative and my solution so far has been to create an interface which contains an enum with the value common for all parts of the system and then create an empty class to implement this interface.

so `enum A implements I` so I can use `A.COMMON_ENUM.ENUM_VALUE`

Now I can create a new `enum B` in some sub part of the system which contains an enum `ADDITIONAL_ENUM` and it implements `I`. So now I can use this:

```
B.COMMON_ENUM.ENUM_VALUE
```

or

```
B.ADDITIONAL_ENUM.ADDED_ENUM_VALUE
```

Is this a ugly solution? - I mean, it works, but just seems *wrong*...

----- UPDATE: -----

The common enum is in the "core" part of the system (which can have multiple front-ends) and the additional enum varies for each front-end. So to use an analogy: Lets say a VEHICLE enum has ENGINE, DOORS and then in my CAR front-end I need to add "WHEELS" and in my BOAT front-end I need to add "PROPELLER"

Code Examples:

```
public interface EnumType {           // I
    public enum Core {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3
    }
}

public enum CommonEnum implements EnumType {     // A

}

public enum AdditionalEnumType implements EnumType {     // B
    public enum Additional {
    VALUEX,
    VALUEY
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the different parts are that you describe, can you show compilable sample code (an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) would be nice)?

Comment: What are the constants that you are storing in your enums? Are they related in some manner?

Comment: @DuncanJones: the answer is *similar*, but the question is quite different (this question notes that it's not possible to extend an enum directly).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, you are right.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the *exact* details of what you are doing, rather than using analogies? I'm struggling to imagine a situation where I would do this for real and perhaps by knowing your real use case, we can see if there are alternatives.

Comment: @Herter: I don't understand why you wrap `Additional` in *another* `enum`type and what use `CommonEnum` has. I'd use only the interface (`EnumType`), `Core` (but outside of the enum) and `Additional` (but implementing `EnumType`).

Comment: @JoachimSauer The reason I wrap Additional in another enum is to get this structure:

EnumType.ADDITIONAL.VALUEX
EnumType.COMMON.VALUE2

and so forth.. just looks cleaner

Comment: Except that you don't get that 'cleaner' look with your solution?! It's more like: `EnumType.Core.VALUE1` `AdditionalEnumType.Additional.VALUEX` and so on... makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a similar pattern, but I don't understand why you've got all that nesting in yours. Mine would look like this:

```
interface SomeType {
  String name();
}

public enum CoreEnum implements SomeType {
  VALUE1,
  VALUE2;
}

public enum AdditionalEnum implements SomeType {
  VALUE3,
  VALUE4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might read about the [typesafe enum pattern](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html) for that purpose. You were alright with introducing the interface. So you should only depend on that interface in your APIs. If the implementation of that interface is done by an enum or class should be of no concern to your API users.

I can't see anything bad about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own classes similar to enum by design

```
public class A {
    A() {}  
    public static final A A1 = new A();
    public static final A A2 = new A();
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    B() {}
    public static final A A3 = new A();
}
```

Comment: This is the type-safe enum pattern, that SpaceTrucker mentioned above..